# vue js not compiling in a laravel v8 project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web, laravel-blade

Do you think you can help me with a laravel/vue js tempalte website called stocky from codecanyon.

I have been trying to add some custom fields to a couple of formss but it wouldnt work due to a problem with npm and vue js.

When running the first time "npm install" it gives me errors(find the attached picture).

Whenever I add something in the backend it gets added successfully but when I make a change on the frontend it doesnt load and doesn't show on the navigator.

package.json

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
        "@pencilpix/vue2-clock-picker": "^0.1.6",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.20.3",
        "@trevoreyre/autocomplete-vue": "^2.2.0",
        "@vee-validate/i18n": "^4.5.3",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "core-js": "^3.19.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "echarts": "^4.9.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.41",
        "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
        "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "targets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-barcode": "^1.3.0",
        "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
        "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
        "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
        "vue-easy-print": "0.0.8",
        "vue-echarts": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
        "vue-excel-xlsx": "^1.2.2",
        "vue-flag-icon": "^1.0.6",
        "vue-good-table": "^2.21.11",
        "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.4.4",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.26.5",
        "vue-image-lightbox-carousel": "^1.0.7",
        "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "vue-localstorage": "^0.6.2",
        "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-mj-daterangepicker": "^0.1.11",
        "vue-navigation-bar": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
        "vue-select": "^3.16.0",
        "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.10",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^3.0.8",
        "vue-upload-multiple-image": "^1.1.6",
        "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.6.8",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
        "vuex": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/composition-api": "^1.2.4",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.7",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-i18n-extractor-plugin": "^2.0.7"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have python2 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this late but might be useful for someone.
I have recently used stocky, and faced same issue,
I am new to laravel and node.js
my issue resolved following below methods

firstly delete package.lock.json file and node_modules folder

then clear cache using command

```
npm cache clear --force
```

then run below

```
npm install cross-env
 
npm install

npm audit fix

npm rebuild node-sass

php artisan optimize
```

all of these installed successfully and was also able to run php artisan serve and npm run watch.

Env details:

```
stocky 3.9
node 12.0.0
php 7.4.1
IIS webserver 10 in windows 11 22H2
```

however the stocky has different versions you also need to make sure the version of node, php and mysql is compatible with the stocky build.
Hope this helps

Note: I am unaware of explaining much on above commands as i am in learning phase. anyone wants to improvise this answer is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue was related to node version i just downgrade node from 16 to 14 and it works fine thank you

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34902482)